# Display Calender only When events is scheduled in Worpdress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

We are Using the_event calendar function free edition . But we need to customize the plugin as displaying the day only when the events occurred. 
How can we do that ?

[image]

hear we need to skip the 3, 4 and 5 row
Link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the_event plugins code and you can show eventmanagres.php file and in thus file you can see function the time slot with the month and year wise.
but for day to day event occurrence you want to create function for this 
array tribe_events_get_current_month_date ( )
string|null tribe_get_start_date ( int $event = null, bool $display_time = true, string $date_format = ’’, string $timezone = null )

using this function you just find out date first to through your database,than now you add this function in existing function, than you get current day event.